# Pronunciation of 世論

Tags: pronunciation, readings, multiple-readings

It seems that 世論 can be pronounced as both よろん and せろん. Are the meanings identical? Is one pronunciation more common than the other?

Comment: My understanding is this is a case where you can freely take your pick. 世論{よろん} and 世論{せろん} seem to be used to mean exactly the same; so do 世論調査{よろんちょうさ} and 世論調査{せろんちょうさ}, with the former (世論{よろん}) seemingly more popular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Practically, Eddie Kal's comment is right: you can use both (no change for nuance) and [よろん is more common (see 5. 言葉の発音)](https://www.bunka.go.jp/tokei_hakusho_shuppan/tokeichosa/kokugo_yoronchosa/h15/).

Historically, 世論 was せろん and 輿論 was よろん. Since 輿 was not included in 当用漢字 (1946), 世論 came to be used for both readings (cf. [Wikipedia article for 輿論](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BC%BF%E8%AB%96#%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%80%8C%E4%B8%96%E8%AB%96%E3%80%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%80%8C%E8%BC%BF%E8%AB%96%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AE%E5%8C%BA%E5%88%A5)). The linked article says 世論/輿論 meant different things up to Taisho era, but the difference is lost now.